# Drag and drop JLabel while preserving the original JLabel

Tags: jlabel

I am working on a GUI that displays an image of a floor plan (JLabel with ImageIcon) and a number of small icons (JLabels with ImageIcon) down the left hand side.  The idea is to be able to select one of the icons and drag and drop it onto a position on the floor plan.  My code is working fine except that when you drag an icon onto the floor plan, I need the original icon to remain in place, so it can be placed in several other positions on the floor plan if required.  So I need to be able to clone the icon that I am moving when the mouse is pressed.

My code below shows a temp fix between the //******** markers but of course this only works correctly for the topmost icon.  I need to somehow clone "Component comp" as a new JLabel.

Below is the relevant part of my code:

```
class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    private Component dragComponent;
    private Sidebar board;
    private Point dragOffset;

    public MouseHandler(Sidebar board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public Sidebar getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Component comp = getBoard().getComponentAt(e.getPoint());            
        if (comp != null) {
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {                                           

                //**************
                String imagePath = "/Downlight 1.gif";
                Image Images = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(imagePath)).getImage();
                String path = "Images" + imagePath;
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path); 
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(icon);
                lbl.setBounds(22, 26, 36, 36);
                lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Images));
                lbl.setOpaque(true);
                Sidebar board = getBoard();
                board.add(lbl, new Point(40, 44));
                board.setComponentZOrder(lbl, 0);
                //**************

                dragComponent = comp;
                dragOffset = new Point();
                dragOffset.x = e.getPoint().x - comp.getX();
                dragOffset.y = e.getPoint().y - comp.getY(); 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (dragComponent != null) {
            board = getBoard();
            Point dragPoint = new Point();
            dragPoint.x = e.getPoint().x - dragOffset.x;
            dragPoint.y = e.getPoint().y - dragOffset.y;
            dragComponent.setLocation(dragPoint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (dragComponent != null) {
            dragComponent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
Thanks in advance for any help with this.
```

Comment: 1) *"Below is the relevant part of my code:"*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Don't add the tag of your IDE unless the question is about the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that enabled me to copy the icon and bounds of the original JLabel to a new JLabel, which replaces the one being dragged:

```
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Component comp = getBoard().getComponentAt(e.getPoint());            
        if (comp != null) {
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {                                           

                JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
                ImageIcon icon = ((ImageIcon)label.getIcon());
                Rectangle rect = label.getBounds(); 
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(icon);
                lbl.setBounds(rect);
                lbl.setVisible(true);;
                lbl.setOpaque(true);
                Mainpanel board = getBoard();
                board.add(lbl);
                board.setComponentZOrder(lbl, 0);

                dragComponent = comp;
                dragOffset = new Point();
                dragOffset.x = e.getPoint().x - comp.getX();
                dragOffset.y = e.getPoint().y - comp.getY(); 

            }
        }
    }
```